# Is there a built-in or common way to serialize a class definition?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I wonder if there is a standard or at least common way to serialize a class definition in .net? **Not** an instance of the class (an object) but the actual class definition itself, e.g.:

```
public class Foo {
      [Required]
      public string Bar { get; set; }

      [Range(1,1000)]
      public int Faz { get; set; }
}

var schema = SomeClass.SerializeDefinition(typeof(Foo));
=> schema is a string I can send somewhere that can now recreate the class
```

Visual Studio can generate WSDLs using wsdl.exe, but I need to do that from code. Unfortunately, Googling mostly yields results on how to serialize objects/instances or how to use external tooling.

I can build something myself using reflection, but before I build my own wheel I'd figured it's worth checking here.

Comment: How would the definition be used?  In the extreme case, you can consider the .NET assembly binary to be an encoding of the class, which you can read using Reflection, but I'm guessing you have a particular consumer in mind for the data.

Comment: @DanBryant In an ideal world, a consumer could create a .net class from it (Dynamic Proxy Class generation basically) . In an acceptable world, a human being would create a class by reading the serialized definition. In an acceptable world with sprinkles, I can validate if a serialized object matches the schema.